# Sentence list to uniqued sentence list by (combined word groups not repeated)

Tags: c#, string, split

Here is nice trouble i'm working on it.

I have a string has multi lines like that;

```
Gözler ne renk olursa olsun, gözyaşları hep aynı renktedir.
Dünyanın en güzel gülüşünü ona vermişler sanki.
Kaybetmekten korktuğum ne varsa kaybettim ben.
Çünkü öyle güzel baktı ki, gökyüzünü gözlerine sığdırmıştı.
Sen gelmek isteseydin, o sokakların hep aynı bana çıkardı.
O değil de benim uzaklara gitmem lazım, çok uzaklara.
Yan yanaydık. Ve şehir böyle mucize görmemişti.
Benim yaşayacağım ne varsa, seninle olsun istiyorum.
```

I'm splitting this string by \n character to a List of string and i do split words by space character and combine word by 2 or three like that;

```
 string[] LineWords = Line.split(' ').ToArray();
 int wordSplitC = 2;
 List<string> CombinedWords = LineWords.Where((word, index) => index + wordSplitC <= LineWords.Length).Select((word, index) => String.Join(" ", LineWords.Skip(index).Take(wordSplitC).Select(r => r.Trim()))).ToList();
```

In example i have combined words like that for first line.
        [image]
Now i should remove duplicate sentences by if sentence has contains an a combined word item at has another sentence.

In this example output string has this modifications:

```
Gözler ne renk olursa olsun, gözyaşları hep aynı renktedir.
Dünyanın en güzel gülüşünü ona vermişler sanki.
Kaybetmekten korktuğum ne varsa kaybettim ben.
Çünkü öyle güzel baktı ki, gökyüzünü gözlerine sığdırmıştı.
**Sen gelmek isteseydin, o sokakların hep aynı bana çıkardı.**
O değil de benim uzaklara gitmem lazım, çok uzaklara.
Yan yanaydık. Ve şehir böyle mucize görmemişti.
**Benim yaşayacağım ne varsa, seninle olsun istiyorum.**
```

1. Should remove sentence at line:5 because of "hep aynı" word is used
   at first line.
2. Should remove sentence at last line because of "ne
       varsa" word is used at line:3

I hope i can understand my problem.

I'm trying something at that picture, but it's not work stable.
[image]

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: You haven't showed us anything apart from splitting strings to words... What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Hello @Fabjan, I added a picture at question. I'm trying that its not stable. Could you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally has a solution for it;

```
        string wordSplitCount = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Word split count", "Enter word split count", "2");
        int wordSplitC = 0;
        int.TryParse(wordSplitCount, out wordSplitC);
        this.richTextBox1.Enabled = false;
        if (wordSplitC > 0)
        {
            List<string> WordList = new List<string>();
            List<string> LineList = this.richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n').ToList();
            LineList.Select((Line, Index) => new { Line, Index }).ToList().ForEach(Item =>
            {
                string[] Words = Item.Line.Split(' ').ToArray();
                List<string> CombinedWords = Words.Where((word, index) => index + wordSplitC <= Words.Length).Select((word, index) => String.Join(" ", Words.Skip(index).Take(wordSplitC).Select(r => removeTurkishCharacters(r).Trim()))).ToList();
                LineList.RemoveAll(x => CombinedWords.Any(c => removeTurkishCharacters(x).Contains(removeTurkishCharacters(c))) && x != Item.Line);
            });
            this.richTextBox2.Text = string.Join("\n", LineList);
            this.richTextBox1.Enabled = true;
        }
```

And here is working example,

[image]

Thanks for everyone.